# deCarta Android API geocode throws Protocol not found exception

Tags: android, geocoding, decarta-android-api

I am using the deCarta Android API to find the GPS Lat/Lng of a street address.  However, whenever I try to use the geocode method of the Geocoder class it always throws the exception:

```
Protocol not found
```

I am passing in a StructuredAddress object populated with the street address for Google:

```
address.toString():
```

1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy
Mountainview, CA 94043

```
ArrayList<GeocodeResponse> results = Geocoder.geocode(address,false);
```

Please advise.

Comment: This should work quite easily. I am not a technical person but if you post your question to the deCarta Dev Zone, you will get an answer. http://developer.decarta.com/forum Thanks, Mike Cottle

Comment: I have cross-posted this issue in the dev forum of deCarta.  I agree, this should be a no-brainer, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it turns out was that I missed setting up the values in the config file:

```
CONFIG.clientName="YOUR_CLIENT_NAME";
CONFIG.clientPassword="YOUR_CLIENT_PASSWORD"; 
CONFIG.host="YOUR_HOST";
CONFIG.configuration="YOUR_CONFIGURATION";
CONFIG.transparentConfiguration="YOUR_TRANSPARENT_CONFIGURATION";
```